# openelec to libreelec update not working

Tags: pi-2, openelec, update

My attempt to upgrade OpenElec 7 on my RP2B to LibreElec is not working as expected.

I currently have OpenElec 7 on my RP2B. I followed the instructions to upgrade to LibreElec  by

- downloading the update .tar file
- copying the tar file into the 'Updates' folder of my SD card
- rebooting

However, OpenElec seems to be ignoring the update file.
I have tries changing the file permissions of the update file, as well as extracting the tar, with no avail.

Reference : https://libreelec.tv/downloads/

UPDATE: I am using berryboot as my boot manager.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am trying to update from libreelec 7.0.1 to libreelec 7.0.3

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. In my case I was using Berryboot. The thing is that Berryboot uses the same kernel for all your OS. I switched to PINN (enhanced version of NOOBS) and it worked ok.

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted. I think you're on to something here. I am also using berryboot. I didn't mention it as I didn't think it was relevant. However, I found that Berryboot keeps things in squashfs and files in the /update directory are not always available to OpenElec upon boot.